# Selenium_jUnit 4 - No runnable methods

Tags: java, selenium, junit, junit4

I've just made a new framework jUnit testing. There is a single class with a simple `@Test` method.

```
package newTry2;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class testApp {

WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.out.println("LOL");
    }   
}
```

But I always get "No runnable methods" after a Junit run. Why? There is my Test annotation! Thanks for the tips!:)

[image: Picture1]
[image: pom.xml]

Comment: How are you running the code? for better troubleshooting i suggest you to right click on the project and run as jUnit test. it will work fine. if not reconfigure the jars.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I'm trying as you wrote it and I get the same result :(

Comment: Use `maven surefire plugin`